# Apache Ambari - Install Wizard Web UI not working

Tags: ambari, hdp

I have some trouble with Apache Ambari 2.7.3 on Ubuntu and its Install Wizard. After the Cluster Name tab, the Web UI blocks the next steps but I can't understand where is the problem. In the web developer console there are some errors:

> Error on XML interpretation: no root element founded Address:
>   http://192.168.1.129:8080/api/v1/persist/CLUSTER_CURRENT_STATUS?_=1545044000929 Row number 1, column 1: CLUSTER_CURRENT_STATUS:1:1
>
> Error on origin mapping: request failed with status 404 URL rsource:
>   http://192.168.1.129:8080/stylesheets/vendor.css URL origin mapping:
>   bootstrap.css.map

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I built ambari 2.7.3 from source on Centos7. The server starts without error, but the cluster creation wizard gets stuck after Step 1, without an error message. In the browser console I can see the same error you mentionned here. Did you find a solution to your problem ?